# Set variable value as 0 and 1 on button click

Tags: ios, buttonclick

I need to post value 0 and 1 of a variable Like.
when I click on first button,value of Like should set as 1 and when i click on other button,value of Like should set as 0.

Any idea how to do,I searched it,didn't got any helpful answer.

Later i succeed : I did it :)

Declare a global variable just above the implementation as shown in code:

```
    static id value;
    @implementation uploadViewController
```

now,set values whatever you want to.

```
  - (IBAction)dislike:(id)sender {
      value=@"0";
    }

   - (IBAction)like:(id)sender {
       value=@"1";
     }
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit more from taking a basic programming course or a basic iOS development course than asking specific questions here at this point. Also, if you still prefer asking this here now, what have you tried? Remember, not a code writing service.

Comment: @Roope Excuse me ?!! i just did it on my own ! i posted in case i fail to do so,i can catch up here. alright !

Comment: @ShikhaSharma What is the issue with your code?

Comment: Excuse you what? A) you didn't provide any code or other context in the question B) the functionality asked about is trivially basic C) you said you did research but clearly not very much. That's how you get identified as a beginner. Thus I suggested a more general resource that would help a beginner much more than asking specific questions one by one about each problem they run into.

Comment: @NiravD No issue I guess, he posted an answer to the question in the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: @Roope i am a beginner only -_- ,this site is for help ,right ?

Comment: @ShikhaSharma Okay, then my initial recommendation stands: I suggest you take a basic programming course or and go from there. And yes, this site is definitely for help. But not for every single small question that comes to mind, this is not a discussion forum in that sense. _Asking_ here is expected to be a last resort resource, while _searching_ here is often one of the first resources to use. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @Roope you know.. i really don't care whatever you say,if i'll have doubts am definitely gonna ask, you're no one to tell me what to ask,cuz if small questions won't be asked then how beginners will get answers to there questions and from where !

Comment: It's not about what I say or what you care about it. It's about the fact that it's a much better and faster way to learn things to take a basic course than trying to start from zero by yourself. Stack Overflow is not a forum for trivial questions that have answers available to in countless online resources already, it's a forum for questions that there seems to be no other available resource for. As you can see from the upvotes in my comments above, others agree with me. No need to get emotional, that's not very professional. People are just trying to help. Please check out the links above.

Comment: @Roope let's just quit this topic here but you should not underestimate anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well! Its very simple.

You just have to declare a global variable and set its value to 0 in action method of first button and set its value to 1 in action method of other button.